# dom-if does not update according to the condition

Tags: templates, data-binding, polymer, conditional-statements

I'm trying to build a simple login system and I have 2 different templates in it: One when the user is not logged in yet (which displays a "sign in" button), and one when the user is logged in (which displays the username)

By default, the first one is displayed. But when the user is logged in, my first template is not destroyed and my second template is not displayed.

```
    <template is="dom-if" if="{{!logged}}" restamp="true">
        <div class="box" id="notLogged">
            <paper-button class="loginButton" on-tap="loginPopup"><iron-icon class="avatar" icon="account-circle"></iron-icon><span id="notLoggedMessage">Sign in</span></paper-button>
        </div>
    </template>

    <template is="dom-if" if="{{logged}}" restamp="true">
        <div class="box" id="logged">
            <paper-button class="loginButton" on-tap="logoutPopup">
                <img src="https://placehold.it/40x40" alt="user avatar" />
            </paper-button>
        </div>
    </template>
```

and now the script. As you can see, I don't use any ajax yet because the service is not done yet. So I'm faking it with "loginOk" value

```
    Polymer({
        is: 'system-login',
        properties: {
            logged: {
                type: Boolean,
                value: false}
        },
        loginPopup: function (e) {
            loginWindow.open();
        },
        logoutPopup: function (e) {
            logoutWindow.open();
        },
        checkLogin: function () {
            var loginOk = 1;
            if (loginOk === 1) {
                this.logged === true;
                loginWindow.close();
            } else if (loginOk === 2) {
                errorMessage.style.display = "inline";
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: When are you invoking `checkLogin` function? Also, its good to use `this.set` method to set property.

Comment: Ha sorry. `checkLogin`is invoked when the user click on "validate" button in a `paper-dialog` (called `loginPopup`in the code above) where he sets his username / password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `this.logged === true;`. `===` in JavaScript is a comparison operator and not an assignment operator. So what your code does is it compares the value and type of `this.true` with `Boolean true` and returns false (which you are not catching).

Changing it to `this.logged = true` should do the trick

Comment: Indeed, you are right. Thanks! Now when I'm logged in, my first template disappear (good), but the second one does not appear...so my problem remains the same, I guess. Any idea?

Comment: can i see your call to `checkLogin`? Or you can yourself check if your function is getting called. You can do this by either using `console.log` of by using breakpoints in dev-tool.

Comment: Yes, I've put a console.log and there is no problem. the function is fully executed without a single error or warning

Comment: Can i have a look at the rest of the code, because I've tried your code by calling `checkLogin` by clicking on `signup` button and everything works fine for me in plunker. Also is there any particular reason you are using `restamp`, because as per polymer's documentation keeping `restamp` to false has performance benefits.